# Want to display XML received from post request as HTML

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, xml, post

I'm currently running a function that retrieves an XML document from another website. I am able to display the returned XML in a console.log where it's contained within #document.

When I try to parse the XML and then add it onto the dom, I get the error "Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null".

My goal is to print out the xml code onto the dom so that everything with "results" tags in the HTML is displayed and can be styled, but I am doing something wrong with the XML parsing.

Here is the code so far:

```
getData();

function getData() {
$.post(url)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( response ),
      $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
      $title = $xml.find( "results" );
      $( "p.test" ).append( response );
   })   
    .fail(function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(error.responseJSON)
   });
}
```

Comment: If the console.log shows it as a document then do not call $.parseXML since its already an xml document

Comment: Thank you! Removing the parseXML worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Musa in the comments of my question, since I was already receiving an XML document, there is no reason to parse the XML. The following change to the code worked perfectly:

```
dataToHubspot();

function dataToHubspot() {
$.post(url)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      var xml = $( response ),
      $title = xml.find( "results" );
      $( "p.test" ).append( $title );
   })   
    .fail(function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(error.responseJSON)
   });
}
```